# 24 hour Date format is lost while parsing

Tags: date, date-formatting, date-parsing

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class DatePatternConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        //                      yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS
        String inputStringDate="2016-01-24 23:48:15.748";

        DateFormat inputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date inputDate=inputDateFormatter.parse(inputStringDate);

        DateFormat outputDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String outputStringDate=outputDateFormatter.format(inputDate);

        System.out.println("Date before Pattern conversion :"+inputStringDate);
        System.out.println("Date after Pattern conversion  :"+outputStringDate);
    }
}
```

The Output will be :

Date before Pattern conversion :2016-01-24 23:48:15.748

Date after Pattern conversion  :01/24/2016 11:48:15

The expected output should have been 01/24/2016 23:48:15 .

While changing the pattern, we are loosing the 24 hour format and hence lost 12 hours in the output date value .
Can anyone help me out to how can we ensure that we get the right 24 formatted output in the above scenario .

Thanks !

Comment: use `HH` instead of `hh`

Comment: Thank  you ! Its working Raviteja !!!